# preg_match_all to find all URL but exclude email

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

I have searched many Stackoverflow regular expression posts but couldn't find my answer.
I am using the following to find all URLs in a given `$text` string:

```
$pattern = "#((http|https|ftp|ftps)://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?#";
```

(agreed there might be more precise/efficient/... but it is not the problem... yet).

Now with this text input:

```
$text = "Website: www.example.com, ";
$text .= "Contact us: http://www.example.com/cu?t=contactus#anchor, ";
$text .= "Email: contact@example.com";
```

Then a

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
```

would return these:

```
www.example.com
http://www.example.com/cu?t=contactus
example.com
```

The last `example.com` comes from the email and I want to be able to exclude it.
I tried many combinations of `[^@]`, `(?!@)` ... to no avail, I am still getting the email results.

The best I could do is to include an optional `@` at the beginning so it would return `@example.com` and then I loop my results to exclude the ones starting with `@`.

Is there any better solution? A single pattern that would not include the sub-strings that are emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example solution without using too advanced features like assertions:

```
<?php

$text = 'ftp://web.com, ';
$text .= "Website: www.example.com, ";
$text .= "Contact us: http://www.example.com/cu?t=contactus#anchor, ";
$text .= "Email: contact@example.com";

$base = "((http|https|ftp|ftps)://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?";

$matches = array(); preg_match_all("#$base#", $text, $matches); var_dump($matches[0]);
$matches = array(); preg_match_all("#\s($base)#", " $text", $matches); var_dump($matches[1]);

?>
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "ftp://web.com"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  [2]=>
  string(37) "http://www.example.com/cu?t=contactus"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "example.com"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "ftp://web.com"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  [2]=>
  string(37) "http://www.example.com/cu?t=contactus"
}
```

Simply check for whitespace before URL but not include it in subpattern. Using `[^@]` won't work because regex would simply match `e` as `[^@]` and `xample.com` as the rest of the match - they would be later merged into a single match.

Comment: It fits my needs for now, I'll take it as a valid answer. Thanks.