# How to match urls as a word using regex without using the standard word boundary?

Tags: java, regex, re2

I am using re2/J for extracting URLs whether they start with regex or not.
I am using a rather simpler pattern,

```
(?i)((https?://)?(([a-z0-9\\-]+[.])*([a-z0-9\\-]+[.][a-z]+/?)([^\\s()<>]*)))
```

However me adding \b in the beginning and at the end is \b isn't helping me much. it is still matching urls that are part of an email.

example.com from email@**example.com** would also be matched. Something that I am trying to avoid. **@** is considered as a non-word character and hence \b treats it as a word boundary.

is there a good alternate solution to this problem?

**EDIT:**

**Note that I am trying to replace urls with html anchor tags** so I am not actually looking for matches. I have to specify a pattern and a replacement with captured groups.

Comment: In re2 that does not support lookarounds, the only workaround is *match* what you do not need and *capture* what you need. See [`(?i)\S+@\S+.\S+|((?:https?://)?(?:[a-z0-9-]+[.])*[a-z0-9-]+[.][a-z]+/?[^\s()<>]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/5QpPux/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  could you elaborate more on capturing. check my edit.

Comment: I do not know if `re2` allows using a callback method inside the regex replacement method. Regular Java regex can do that with `Matcher#appendReplacement`.

Comment: re2 seems to have an implementation of [```Matcher#appendReplacement```](https://github.com/google/re2j/blob/master/java/com/google/re2j/Matcher.java)

Comment: See http://ideone.com/VPn2wl (in the top comment regex, I forgot to escape the dot).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a ton that solves a lot of other problems I have. Once I test it out with re2J and if it works well, I will let you know, you can put this as an answer.

Comment: Amogh, have you had time to [test out my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41037589/3832970)? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The usual "trick" when you need to "skip" some match and replace another is to match and *capture* what you need and just match what you do not need. Since the replacement pattern differs for both contexts, you should be able to analyze the match object, and [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](https://github.com/google/re2j/blob/master/java/com/google/re2j/Matcher.java#L333) provides this functionality:

```
 String s = "some@domain.com\ndomain.com\nwww.domain.com\nhttp://www.domain.com\nhttps://www.domain.com";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+|((?:https?://)?(?:[a-z0-9-]+[.])*[a-z0-9-]+[.][a-z]+/?[^\\s()<>]*)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, "<a href=\"" + m.group(1) + "\">" + m.group(1) + "</a>");
    }
    else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group());
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString()); // Demo output
```

[Online Java demo](http://ideone.com/VPn2wl) (with `java.util.regex` that uses the same technique)

**Pattern details**:

- `\\S+@\\S+\\.\\S+` - match something that resembles an email (1+ non-whitespaces, `@`, 1+ non-whitespaces, `.` and again 1+ non-whitespaces)
- `|` - or
- `((?:https?://)?(?:[a-z0-9-]+[.])*[a-z0-9-]+[.][a-z]+/?[^\\s() <>]*)` - Group 1 capturing your pattern.

If Group 1 matches, it is not `null`, and we need to wrap it into a tag. Else, jsut re-insert the whole match back.

Answer (score 0):

For email@example.com regex would simply match e as [^@] and xample.com as the rest of the match - they would be later merged into a single match.
Simply check for whitespace before URL but not include it in subpattern.

Have a look, this can help you. [preg_match_all to find all URL but exclude email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271401/preg-match-all-to-find-all-url-but-exclude-email)

Comment: And what if `@@example.com` should get extracted? Or an URL at the start of the string?